# How do you clone a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I can not find much information on how to do this. How do you get a rails app to work after you clone it from github? When I try to start the server it just gives me an error `Could not find activesupport-3.0.7 in any of the sources`. I assume this is because it is not an actual rails app; just a directory with files in it.

Comment: bundle install in app dir will install your dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the `Gemfile.lock` file, run `bundle install` and migrate your database.

Answer (score 6):

After cloning github project you will have to install the gems by running 'bundle install'. 
Then database has to be created and populated (optionally)

```
->git clone git@github.com:Project/project.git [A public / private project of github]
->cd project
->bundle install     #installs gems
->rake db:migrate    #creates db 
->rake db:seed       #populate db with seed data (optional)
->rails server       #start server
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the command

```
bundle install
```

?